# postgresql: How to concatenate two regexp_matches()

Tags: regex, postgresql

I'm trying to extract both ints and chars from names such as 123A America, 234B Britania.
I only want the the number and the attached letter (i.e. 123A) .
I'm using regexp_matches(name, '(\d+)(\D)') and it results as:

`{123,A}, 
{456,B}`

I thought using concatenation, getting the first element of an array and the second element using two different functions
`(regexp_matches(name, '(\d+)(\D)' )) [1] || (regexp_matches(name, '(\d+)(\D)' )) [2]`

But it generates an error:
`ERROR:  functions and operators can take at most one set argument`

How can I get the two element as one string?

Comment: What, in general, does the error message refer to? i.e. Why does, what seems to be a simple value concatenation, cause ERROR: functions and operators can take at most one set argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to get the two items you're searching for as different sets, just get them as a single set.  Remove the `)(` between `\d+` and `\D` and that will return a set containing the entire string you're looking for.

Results in this - 
`regexp_matches('123A America, 234B Britania', '(\d+\D)' )`

This will only find the first match.  To get all matching substrings, use the `g` flag - 
`regexp_matches('123A America, 234B Britania', '(\d+\D)', 'g')`

Answer (score 0):

good answer by @Scott S however if you can't achieve what you need within one capture group the solution is to write a function, assign the regexp result to a variable and then use it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION do_something(_input character varying)
  RETURNS character varying AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    matches text[];
BEGIN
    matches := regexp_matches(_input, '^([0-9]{1,}_[^_]{1,})_[a-z]{1,}(.*)$','i');
    return substring(matches[1], 0, 24)||matches[2];
END
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```