# Pick only the alphabets and not the description from a given string

Tags: regex

I am a newbie to Regex and require help with the following:

I have strings like - `B - Comp-Band Disk,C - Check Oncoming Private,D - DL Procurement Outer`. Is there a Regex expression which I could use to change string to `B,C,D`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Input string `B - Comp-Band Disk,C - Check Oncoming Private,D - DL Procurement Outer` -> Expected Output `B,C,D`. Is there a POSIX Regex expression for this? Are you able to understand the question now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:(?:^|,)(\w))
```

##### Regex Explanation

- `(?:` Non-capturing group

  - `(?:` Non-capturing group

    - `^|,` Match start of the string or `,`
  - `)` Close non-capturing group
  - `(` Capturing group

    - `\w` Match any word character
  - `)` Close group
- `)` Close non-capturing group

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HlegU1/1)

Comment: I'm very thankful for your answer and time! I'm trying to work with this in PostgreSQL but I'm not able to get this to work. Is this POSIX Regex? Upvoting your answer since it is helpful!

Comment: Update: I am only getting `B` instead of `B,C,D` while using it

Comment: You should use `g` (global) flag to get all matches. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36537834/multiple-matches-with-postgres-regexp-matches#answer-36539891) answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being a pedant but this returns an array with one row each for each match - {B}, {C}, {D} in three separate rows, which does not help solve my problem.. I would really appreciate a single array {B,C,D} or better yet a string `B,C,D` (viz. Excluding all text between '-' and ',')

Comment: Could you try `SELECT string_agg(regexp_matches(fieldname, '(?:(?:^|,)(\w))', 'g'), ',')`

Comment: This didn't work but a function called `array_to_string` worked but I am still getting the results in separate rows. Can you please refer this answer and see if your Regex expression can be modified so that I get a single array / result set? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19637811/postgresql-how-to-concatenate-two-regexp-matches

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT array_to_string(regexp_matches(fieldname, '(?:(?:^|,)(\w))', 'g'), ',')`?

Comment: Yes, I have. This returns 3 separate rows (Something like this) - 
  `ID   Value`
    `1    B`
    `1    C`
    `1    D`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245423/discussion-between-karthik-ghorpade-and-artyom-vancyan).

Comment: @karthik_ghorpade, Next works for me. Please try this: `SELECT array_to_string(ARRAY(SELECT regexp_matches(fieldname, '(?:(?:^|,)(\w))', 'g') FROM tablename), ',')` changing the fieldname and tablename